# Need to extract between <h3>, <li> and <strong> using applescript

Tags: applescript

I am a completely new to Applescript, I think that this is the simplest script that you can imagine, but I still can't get it working.

What I want to do is:

1. Get the html code from the page
2. Get name from between  tag
3. Get columns name from between `<strong>` tags
4. Get values for columns from between `<*li><strong>any value<*/strong>` and `</li>`
5. Create excel file with 1st column "Name" + value from 2, and multiple columns with the title from 3 and it's values from 4.

The code:

```
<pre>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>NAME</h3>  
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul class="circle">
                <li><strong>Admin: </strong>Name</li>
                <li><strong>Phone </strong>+XX XX XXX XXX</li>
                <li><strong>Email: </strong><a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><strong></strong></li>
                <li><strong>Title: </strong>value</li>
                <li><strong>Title: </strong>value</li>
                <li><strong>Title: </strong>value</li>
                <li><strong>Title: </strong>value</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)


[3. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for substrings in AppleScript as such:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<strong>"
```

Then you can refer to each delimited item (what's between each delimiter) with `text item #` (where # is a number), or get the full list of delimited items with `every text item`.

By doing this, you can slice your text, get the text item, set the delimiters again to refine what you got, get the next text item you need from that, etc until you have the substring you want. You can make it more efficient by putting it into a subroutine (function).

When AppleScript's text item delimiters are set, they will also be inserted between list elements when you convert a list of strings into a string via `as string`. This also allows you to do a wholesale find/replace operation easily by getting your list of text items, changing the delimiters, and then rejoining them with `as string`.

It's good practice to always `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""` when you're done with them being something else. (Some people consider it better practice to save them in a variable first before changing them, e.g. `set oldDelims to applescript's text item delimiters`, and then change them back to that, but that's not my personal style.)